# Where is the proper place to remove subview?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

In my Cocos2D layer init method I create UIScrollView subclass and add it to OpenGL view:

```
SAScrollView *sv = [...];
CCGLView *eaglView = (CCGLView*)[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view];
[eaglView addSubview:sv];
```

Now what is the proper place to remove that view? I need to have 2 places for removal for different cases a) before any animation started on scene removal and b) after animation finished on scene.

Comment: onexittransiriondidstart & onenter(transitiondidfinish)

Comment: I think last two methods are for arriving to scene, not for leaving it.

Comment: also wondering if `cleanup` method is appropriate place for that.

Comment: thanks anyway. You can copy this as an answer so I can accept, if you wish. Otherwise I will delete this later.